# How are custom error pages configured for uncaught exceptions in WebSphere Portal portlets?

Tags: exception, error-handling, websphere, portlet, portal

Out of the box WebSphere Portal displays a generic "This portlet is temporarily disabled." message for any portlet that throws an uncaught exception.

Does anyone know how how this can be overridden - preferably to provide custom error pages for specific exceptions in the same way error pages can be configured in the web.xml of a standard J2EE app?

Using the web.xml of the portlet to define error pages for exceptions does not work. Can't find any documentation on this anywhere.

Using WebSphere Portal 6.1.5, JSR 286 portlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out - the message is taken from the inside of the portletRender tag in the skin, e.g:

```
<portal-skin:portletRender> 
    <span style="color:#FF0000;"><portal-fmt:problem bundle="nls.problem"/></span> 
</portal-skin:portletRender>
```

So it must be defined in the Theme - not on a per-portlet basis, but as JSP code is supported in the tag body more complex behaviour can be specified.